# Deleting the trigger through apex code

Tags: trigger, tooling-api

I want to delete the apex trigger using code.I used tooling API to create a trigger dynamically through apex code...

Now I want to delete the trigger on click of one button in code itself, but not able to delete..getting following.

```
DML not allowed on Apex Trigger
```

Comment: Can you add the Apex code that you are using to attempt the delete of the trigger?

Comment: ApexTrigger a = [select id,name from apextrigger];
delete a; and same  error is coming 'DML not allowed on ApexTrigger"

Answer (score 1):

To delete a Trigger you have to use the [tooling_API](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/tree/apex-toolingapi-rest) , download and copy it in your classes folder

Add this function into the class "ToolingAPI.cls"

```
public ToolingAPI.SaveResult deleteTrigger(Id sobjectId)
{
    return (ToolingAPI.SaveResult) submitRestCallAndDeserialize(
        '/sobjects/'+'ApexTrigger'+'/'+sobjectId
        ,ToolingAPI.SaveResult.class
        ,'DELETE'
    );
}
```

And in you code you have to call the function like this:

```
public static void deleteTrigger(String theName)
{
    ApexTrigger theTriggerToDelete=null;
    //catch the trigger to delete
    try
    {
        theTriggerToDelete = [select id,name from apextrigger where Name=:theName]; 
    }
    catch(System.QueryException e)
    {
        system.debug('bug = ' + e.getMessage());
    }
    if(theTriggerToDelete == null)
        return;
    //catch the id of the trigger to delete
    ID theIdOfTheTriggerToDelete =theTriggerToDelete.Id;
    //using toolingAPI
    ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();

    //delete the trigger
    try
    {
        toolingAPI.deleteTrigger(theIdOfTheTriggerToDelete);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        system.debug('bug = ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run this successfully in a production org?

Comment: Yes its works fine

Comment: running user needs:  Customize Application permission?  Author Apex permission?

Comment: Of course ,only administrator with Author Apex permission can run it .